# Hibernate not set foreign key

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have this model

```
public class Customer {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long id;

@OneToOne
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
private Address registred_address_id;

@OneToOne
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
private Address actual_address_id;
...
```

And I have this method

```
private Customer addCustomer(String first_name, String last_name, String middle_name, String sex, Address address) {
    Customer customer = new Customer(first_name, last_name, middle_name, sex);
    customer.setActual_address_id(address);
    customer.setRegistered_address_id(address);
    customerRepo.save(customer);
    return customer;
}
```

But hibernate not set actual_address_id and registered_address_id (it,s OneToOne)

> Hibernate:
> insert
> into
> customer
> (first_name, last_name, middle_name, sex)
> values
> (?, ?, ?, ?)
> 2021-03-18 14:01:58.340  WARN 12836 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 23502
> 2021-03-18 14:01:58.340 ERROR 12836 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ОШИБКА: значение NULL в столбце "registred_address_id" отношения "customer" нарушает ограничение NOT NULL
> Подробности: Ошибочная строка содержит (6, null, null, null, null, null, male).

Comment: please translate the error message

Comment: ERROR: NULL in column "registred_address_id" of relationship "customer" violates NOT NULL constraint Details: The error line contains (6, null, null, null, null, null, male).

Comment: @SeventhDonkey When you use `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn`, it's mean that id will be derived from `Address` entity. This is probably not what you want. See [this section](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#identifiers-derived) of documentation

Comment: @SternK why? Customer must have adress from table address.

Comment: @SeventhDonkey I see you use `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)` on Customer.id , so from this point it looks like you want generate `Customer.id`, but when you use `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn` the Customer.id should be setted by Address.id, see example from the documentation (from above link)

Comment: @SeventhDonkey I would suggest you just add two foreign keys to address table (for example `reg_address_id` and `act_address_id`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mapping is contradictory.

From one side you want `Customer.id` to be generated by database after its insert. This is what `GenerationType.IDENTITY` [actually mean](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#identifiers-generators-identity).

From another side you try to use `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn` what mean `Customer.id` should be set by `Address.id`. The correct mapping for `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn` should look something like this:

```java
@Entity
public class Customer {

  @Id
  private long id;

  @OneToOne
  @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
  private Address address;
 
  public void setAddress(Address address) {
     this.address = address;
     this.id = address.getId();
  }
  // ... 
}
```

but this will not fit your requirements.

So, I would suggest you correct your customer table like this:

```sql
create table customer
(
   id bigserial not null,
   reg_address_id bigint,
   act_address_id bigint,
   -- ...
   primary key(id),
   foreign key(reg_address_id) references address(id),
   foreign key(act_address_id) references address(id)
);
```

and then use the following mapping:

```java
@Entity
public class Customer {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  @OneToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "reg_address_id")
  private Address registredAddress;

  @OneToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "act_address_id")
  private Address actualAddress;

  // ... 
}
```